# Set restriction code automatically when i update my iPhone to iOS 9

Tags: iphone, password, error, ios

I didn't set restriction code on my phone, when i update on iOS 9 it shows pass code and i don't know about it.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try 2580. Dont know if this is default or a forgotten password of mine that i just happened to remember but i would give it a shot. It worked for me.